# Warnings on build with Geolocation classes

Tags: iphone

I work yet on simulator and I am waiting for the test on the device, while waiting I wish to share with you my code hoping you to help me figure out the causes of **5 warnings**
my app is composed from 2 classes : CoreLocationController and GeoLocationViewController .

the CoreLocationController is the class which suppose to act as a Core Location Manager Delegate. This class will receive messages from the Core Location framework containing the raw data and will then pass this to our view controller class later on. 
**CoreLocationController.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@protocol CoreLocationControllerDelegate
@required
-(void)LocationUpdate:(CLLocation*)location;//Our location updates are sent here
-(void)locationError:(NSError*)error;//Any errors are sent here
@end
@interface CoreLocationController : NSObject<CLLocationManagerDelegate> {

    CLLocationManager *locMgr;
    id delegate;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)CLLocationManager *locMgr;
@property(nonatomic,assign)id delegate;
@end
```

**CoreLocationController.m**

```
 #import "CoreLocationController.h"
    @implementation CoreLocationController

    @synthesize locMgr,delegate;

    -(id)init{

        self=[super init];
        if(self!=nil)   {

            self.locMgr=[[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];//create new instance of locMgr
            self.locMgr.delegate=self;//set the delegate as self

        }
        return self;    
    }


    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation*)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation*)oldLocation  {   


        if([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CoreLocationControllerDelegate)])    {


            //check if the class assigning itself as the delegate conforms to our protocol. If not,, the message will go now here. Not good
            [self.delegate LocationUpdate:newLocation];

        }

    }


    -(void)LocationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error   {

        if([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CoreLocationControllerDelegate)])    {
        //check if the class assigning it self as the delegate conforms to our protocol.If    not, the message will go now here. Not good
            [self.delegate locationError:error];
        }
    }

    -(void)dealloc  {   
        [self.locMgr release];
        [super dealloc];

    }
    @end
```

**GeoLocationViewController.h :**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CoreLocationController.h"
@interface GeoLocationViewController : UIViewController <CoreLocationControllerDelegate> {

    CoreLocationController *CLController;
    IBOutlet UILabel *locLabel;

}
@property (nonatomic,retain)CoreLocationController *CLController;
@end
```

**GeoLocationViewController.m :**

```
#import "GeoLocationViewController.h"

@implementation GeoLocationViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CLController=[[CoreLocationController alloc] init];
    CLController.delegate=self;
    [CLController.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location    {

    locLabel.text=[location description];

}
-(void)locationError:(NSError *)error   {

    locLabel.text=[error description];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}
- (void)dealloc {

    [CLController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

**Now for the warnings I got :**

```
warning: property 'CLController' requires method '-CLController' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation


 warning: property 'CLController' requires the method 'setCLController:' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation


 warning: incomplete implementation of class 'GeoLocationViewController'


 warning: method definition for '-LocationUpdate:' not found


warning: class 'GeoLocationViewController' does not fully implement the 'CoreLocationControllerDelegate' protocol
```

Last question please, if my build run successufully, but my code doesn't show any informations about geolocation, should I wait to test my build on device to judge on it ??

Comment: did you even look at the warnings before copypasting them here?

Comment: well, ok for example i don't know what this : warning: incomplete implementation of class 'GeoLocationViewController' does mean, i always implement some methods and left others commented :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first warning (and the next two, which are the same thing):

```
warning: property 'CLController' requires method '-CLController' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation
```

It means, you need to @synthesize CLController in your GeoLocationViewController.m file after @implementation. It will still work, though, because you are not referencing it as a property inside the class (i.e. you are not referencing it with `self.CLController` but just `CLController`.  So just put `@synthesize CLController` after @implementation for GeoLocationViewController.m.

The second error

```
warning: incomplete implementation of class 'GeoLocationViewController'
warning: method definition for '-LocationUpdate:' not found
```

You did not specify LocationUpdate as a method in your GeoLocationViewController.h file.

Comment: and what about : warning: class 'GeoLocationViewController' does not fully implement the 'CoreLocationControllerDelegate' protocol   should i implement the whole protocol!! or just ignore it

Comment: You should never ignore warnings, especially in Objective-C because they usually result in runtime crashes because it is a message-based language - many things will not generate compile-time errors, but will crash during runtime. That said, yes, I see now what the problem is: in your delegate, you have LocationUpdate defined, but below you implement it with a lower-case L. Try changing it to uppercase in your implementation to match the protocol